# Quokka in VSCode through WSL's Node possible?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, quokka.js

Quokka in VSCode trough WSL's Node possible?

When I link to bash.exe, though I don't know what to link too, it gives me:

```
​​GNU long options:​​
​​  --debug​​
​​  --debugger​​
​​  --dump-po-strings​​
​​  --dump-strings​​
​​  --help​​
​​  --init-file​​
​​  --login​​
​​  --noediting​​
​​  --noprofile​​
​​  --norc​​
​​  --posix​​
​​  --rcfile​​
​​  --restricted​​
​​  --verbose​​
​​  --version​​
​​Shell options:​​
​​  -ilrsD or -c command or -O shopt_option     (invocation only)​​
​​  -abefhkmnptuvxBCHP or -o option​​
​​​​
```

when I use a batch file I get with node %*

```
​​module.js:557​​
​​    throw err;​​
​​    ^​​

​​Error: Cannot find module 'path\to\file/C:\Users\CoLd As IcE\.vscode\extensions\WallabyJs.quokka-vscode-1.0.94\dist\wallaby\server.js'​​
​​    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)​​
​​    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)​​
​​    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)​​
​​    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:193:16)​​
​​    at bootstrap_node.js:617:3​​
```

and when I use when I use a batch file I get with node % *

```
​​Error: Cannot find module 'path\to\file\***newpath***/C:\Users\CoLd As IcE\.vscode\extensions\WallabyJs.quokka-vscode-1.0.94\dist\wallaby\server.js'​​
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Yes it is.

Do the below - (these docs are very well maintained at the moment)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl

Then the rest should be pretty straight forward from your VS Code installation.
To install VS Code in the first place, simply get it from the Microsoft Store and install. Once that is done, launch VS Code and find the extension in the extensions tab and install. It is called "Remote - WSL"

Once the installation on Windows is set up, go to Windows Terminal / bash and the folder you want to work in. ~/home/{myUserName}/{myNewProject}

then run
code .
from the folder you want to code in, where "." represents current working directory

Note: If there is an update, it will first download and install the latest version before launching VS Code on your Windows desktop.